# where can i get the flex projects for practice?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i want to practice sample projects to make me perfect in flex development. Where can i get the sample flex projects with sourcecode.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

- [Simple Flex Tutorial](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/490.cfm)

Here are some detailed useful tutorials with source code:

- [Flex HTTPService with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlexHttpServiceAndASP_Net.aspx)
- [Flex Communication with ASP.NET WebService](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlexASPWebService.aspx)
- [Using Flex to build your real-time chart](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/Flex_chart.aspx)
- [Building and Querying Secure SSO Services Using Axis and Flex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/SSO-Axis-Flex.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[blog.flexexamples.com](http://blog.flexexamples.com) is another good site which demonstrates how to use each flex component (flex 2,3 and 4)